# pandas dataframe check if a value in a specific location is a NaN value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

in my program i need to find out if a single value in my pandas.DataFrame is either a NaN or not?
i figured:

```
print(df.loc[index, 'Column1'])
```

output:

```
nan
```

but this script works like a charm

```
nullV = None
print(nullV == None)
```

output:

```
True
```

not this though

```
print(df.loc[39, 'booking'] == None)
```

output:

```
False
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between `nan` and `None`.  A value of `nan` still allows the column to be a 64-bit float dtype, instead of getting converted to the `object` dtype.

To check if it is `nan`, use:

```py
pd.isna(df.loc[index, 'Column1'])
```

Comment: This won't work. `df.loc[index, 'Column1']` returns a single value, not a Series or DataFrame. The value, let's say a float, doesn't contain an `isna` method.  You should use `pandas.isnull` or `numpy.isnan` instead.

Comment: @HarryPlotter, you are right, this is just a single value and so must be wrapped in the `pd.isna` fucntion

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```py
import numpy as np

np.isnan(df.loc[39, 'booking'])
```